# Want to add MVC4 to WebForms app, don't have access to global.asax file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I did some research on "mixing and matching" with mvc4 and webforms and came across a few links, notably [This one.](http://blogs.ibs.com/Scott.Zischerk/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20)

Seems doable, except that I'd like to add this to an existing webforms app whose global.asax codebehind I don't have access to. I update my part of the current webforms app by dropping my dlls in the bin folder of the application root.

Is there another way for me to register the routes, filters and bundles if I can't do it in the application_start method in the global.asax?

In other words, where would this code go?

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to hack it in in some ugly way or another so the best solution would be to persuade the guys controlling global.asax to give you some kind of hook.

But the routes could ve registered anywhere as long as it only happens once and early in the application lifetime, so perhaps a static constructor somewhere?

The problem would them be to ensure that the type holding the ctor is accessed during app start which could introduce a new headache but it could be doable.

But again: some kind of hook in the startup event would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can get them to modify the startup event. It's only a few lines so hopefully the bellyaching will be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `App_Start` folder. According to the [article on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492833/ASP-NET-MVC-4-Part-2-Project-Items#15):

> "And also we can avoid touching Global.asax file when using any new
>   nugget packages that needs to use Application_Start from Global.asax"